# How to increase heap space and debug in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory

The issue is that running from cmd is not very good for debugging . 
I need to debug the code , so is there any way i could increase heap and debug in eclipse .

I tried increasing heap in `control panel - > java -> view - > 6g`

but still get the java out of memory in eclipse

Comment: Hint: there's a file called `eclipse.ini` in your installation directory.

Comment: The `eclipse.ini` settings change the heap space for Eclipse itself, the `Run Configurations` settings change the heap for programs you run from within Eclipse.

Comment: @greg-449 you can do that at eclipse level - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995185/how-to-increase-heap-space-and-debug-in-eclipse/60880018#60880018

Answer (score 3):

1. Click the arrow next to the run button, and select Run Configurations...
2. Select your application from the left list
3. Go to Arguments
4. In VM arguments add `-Xmx6g -Xms2g`
5. Click Apply.

This will increase the heap size for that launch configuration to 6G.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing in the eclipse.ini file.
Here is an example configuration

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:PermSize=256M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change default jvm args which will apply to all Run/Debug configurations and you don't have to change individual configuration.

In eclipse go to `Window -> Preference -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Edit default JRE`. There add `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m` under `Default VM arguments`